# How to use QtTest with qbs

Tags: qt, qbs, qttest

I can't find clear example of building tests with qbs.
I tried like this

```
import qbs

CppApplication {
  consoleApplication: true

  files: [ "TestTask.h", "TestTask.cpp" ]
  Depends { name: "Qt"; submodules: [ "core", "testlib" ] }
}
```

TestTask is a QObject subclass. 
But compiler says that I missed main() function.

Comment: Does TestTaks.cpp have a QTEST_MAIN()? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#QTEST_MAIN

Comment: thanks, I missed it

Answer (score 0):

For compile test your need main.cpp. For example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTest>
#include "TestTask.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTest::qExec(new TestTask, argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Your must also add main.cpp in files (qbs file).